# Generate a random Y for a sprite

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I need some help (duh). I want to generate a random Y position for my game in cocos2d.

So the situation goes like this:
The game spawns a platform every 0.2 second. The iPhone / iPad is in landscape mode. Platform appear on the right of the screen (bigger x than width so that the platform appears outside the screen) and starts moving towards the left end of the screen using `CCMoveTo`.
I pick a random Y for every platform. The problem is that I do not want to spawn a platform on top of another. This means that I need to make a randY which is not "already taken".
The code I've tried so far is this:

```
//this is a part of code from my addPlatform function. This part in particular cares for the generation of my Y coordinate.
int randY = arc4random() % (int)(3 * (winSize.height/4)); //This prevents to spawn a Y larger than 3/4 of the screen

//here I would like to loop long enough to find a good Y
while (![self isGoodPlatformY:randY])
{
    randY = arc4random() % (int)(3 * (winSize.height/4));
}
```

The next part is my `isGoodPlatformY` function

```
- (bool)isGoodPlatformY:(int)platY
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    int padding = 100;
    bool ok = true;
    for (CCSprite *body in [self children])
    {
        if (body.tag > platformBody)
        {
            if (body.position.x < (winSize.width - padding))
            {
                if (abs(body.position.y - platY) < 20)
                {
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return ok;
}
```

I loop through all the bodies with larger tag than my platform. I have different types of platform which I separate by using tag. If the body is a platform I first check the X coordinate. If the platform is enough away (padding) I can spawn a new one at that exact point so I check the next one. If not I want to check the Y of that platform. If the Y coordinate is less than 20 pixels in this case I must find a new Y so thats why set the bool to false and return it after the for loop.
I know there is no need for those curly brackets but I was testing some other stuff, thats why I put them there.

This doesn't seem to work. Hope I made myself clear what I want to accomplish. Any help from your side would be much appreciated. Hope I didn't miss something too newbie style :)

I tagged the question in other languages to because this problem could occur "everywhere".

Comment: If the problem can occur "everywhere" (and it can), you should have used pseudocode instead of asking someone, for example, fluent in C# to parse objective-c.

Comment: Just a sidenote, those curly brackets are just fine the way they are. There is generally no need to "optimize" them away other than lazy typing (which usually, later on does take its toll).

Comment: `(body.position.x < (winSize.width - padding))` it can be on another line (other Y), isn't it? Or I don't get this condition? I it looks to me as platforms from other lines can prevent your new to be spawned?

Comment: I mean it should be something like:`(body.position.x < (winSize.width - padding) && (body.position.y == playY))`?

Comment: The `body.position.x < (winSize.width - padding)` is for checking if a platform is enough "to the left" already. So if a platform would have an x value of 100 and my winSize.width was 1000 I could easily spawn a platform there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have discovered that I can answer my own questions :) (silly me). So yeah, the problem was fixed a long time ago but to anyone who might be reading this, the solution was to change the line:

```
if (body.position.x < (winSize.width - padding))
```

To:

```
if (body.position.x > (winSize.width - padding))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the spawned platforms have the same tag as you mentioned that you are using tags to separate different types of platforms.

All previous platforms will not return true for this line

```
if (body.tag > platformBody)
```

because they all have the same tag, you will compare (1 > 1) which is false.

Therefore your method will always return YES (which is your default value for ok) and will never check to see if the platforms collide with each other.

I recommend stepping through the method to see if this is the case.

Comment: No platformBody has the value of 100. Other platform begin win 101 and so on.

Comment: Yes but if every platform you create has the value of 100 they will never be tested. In the case that you are making the tag increment your platformBody tag will never be less than the other platforms as well.

Comment: Yes I know. My defines look like this `#define platformBody 100
#define defaultPlatform 101
#define bouncePlatform 102
#define invisiblePlatform 103`. This is not the problem. Platforms get tags 101 and more.